# Is it possible to relax MILP and get the same solution as the original MILP?

Tags: python-3.x, cplex

My problem is MILP problem, I relax one of the binary variables and use benders decomposition to solve the relaxed problem. The program runs successfully and a result is given. However, the result is not valid which means some of the original constraints are not satisfied.

My original MILP problem can always give correct results. Does it mean that my original constraints are not strong enough to secure a valid result for the relaxed MILP model?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What makes you think the result is not valid? What is the value of [Cplex.solution.get_status()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.SolutionInterface-class.html#get_status)?

Comment: The valid result should be a valid route which means all passengers will be picked up and deliver to their corresponding destinations. Because the route given by BD is not valid which means some passengers are not picked up. The result for Cplex.solution.get_status() is optimal though. So I am thining if my original constraints are not strong.

Comment: What happens if you try to feed the solution given by your BD model into your original MILP (i.e., using the [MIP_starts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.MIPStartsInterface-class.html) interface)? Maybe that will shed some light on things?

Comment: As for your more general question about the theory of MILP and BD, maybe you'll have better luck asking on the official IBM developerWorks [forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002059) for CPLEX?

Comment: I think this problem happens quite often in LP relaxation. Maybe I need to round the solution back to integers if necessary. Because the LP relaxed model gives us the lower bound. Yes, you are right, maybe I should get help from the official IBM developerWorks forum for CPLEX. Thank you so much.